# iPad UIPopOverControllers' container view does not accept touch gestures

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a very simple View with a text label and an info button that i am displaying in a UIPoOverController.
I am explicitly setting setUserInteractionEnabled:YES for my button as well as the view containing the UIButton.
However, when i present my UIPopoverController, i am not able to press the button and hence dismiss any action associated to that button.

Any ideas?

Comment: Works for me now. I had the button in a view that was a  subview of UIViewController's view. The parent view had it's frame set to CGRectZero. For some reason setting CGRectZero made all controls in my subview not user intractable. May be this is a bug in Cocoa, no idea though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me now. I had the button in a view that was a subview of UIViewController's view. The parent view had it's frame set to CGRectZero. For some reason setting CGRectZero made all controls in my subview not user intractable. May be this is a bug in Cocoa, no idea though

Comment: This is a feature, not a bug. Views only accept touch events which are "inside" them (see `-hitTest:withEvent:`). The alternative is potentially iterating over every view in the hierarchy, which is not really sensible.